# How to build relationship standard / custom object

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, data-model

I have the following standard and custom objects and I'm little lost how to build the relationship, let me first describe you my data model and then what I'm looking for.

my data model is:

```
Standard object -> Account

Custom object -> 
                 EmployeeManagement__c
                 EmployeeTicket__c
                 EmployeeProject__c
```

There is a relationship between `EmployeeProject ==> EmployeTicket` using  `Master/Detail` relationship, Master is `EmployeeProject`.

`EmployeeProject__c has a lookup to Account`

`EmployeeManagement__c has a lookup to Account`

my question, how I can see all the `EmployeeTicket` records based on the Account on the `EmployeeManagement` records?

Meaning, I will have a related list in the EmployeeManagement page layout where I will see all the records that associated with same `Account Name` as is in the EmployeeTicket

Comment: Related lists are set up on your Object Page layout. However, your requirement is too complex for configuration, and you will need to build a custom component (you can only show related object fields on the related lists, however for your logic you are traversing multiple objects).

Answer (score 1):

Related lists are generated based on the lookup fields. You can see the EmployeeTicketList on EmployeeProject__c because there is a direct relationship.
What you are asking is not possible. You don't have a choice rather than building a custom component that does the filtering and fetch ing based on the filtering criteria. Something like a LWC Component which would render all the Employee Tickets where

> SELECT , FROM EmployeeTicket WHERE EmployeeTicket.AccountId == EmployeeManagement.AccountId

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully this is possible in Lightning Experience and Lightning App Builder, since we can include Related Lists from Parent Records.

In the following example, I'm displaying the `Contacts` Related List from the Parent `Account` on the `Opportunity` Lightning Record Page. As long as the `EmployeeManagement__c` has the same Parent Account as the `EmployeeTicket__c` records, the `EmployeeTicket__c` records will appear in the Parent Record Related List.

(To access the Lightning Record Page for `EmployeeManagement__c`, go to a record and then click the `Edit Page` dropdown on the gear icon in the top-righthand corner)

[image]